# Reading recustructed vector from autoencoder in DL4J

Tags: autoencoder, deeplearning4j, dl4j

My goal is to have an autoencoding network where I can train the identity function and then do forward passes yielding a reconstruction of the input.

For this, I'm trying to use `VariationalAutoencoder`, e.g. something like:

```java
MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
                .seed(77147718)
                .trainingWorkspaceMode(WorkspaceMode.NONE)
                .gradientNormalization(GradientNormalization.ClipElementWiseAbsoluteValue)
                .gradientNormalizationThreshold(1.0)
                .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.CONJUGATE_GRADIENT)
                .list()
                .layer(0, new VariationalAutoencoder.Builder()
                        .activation(Activation.LEAKYRELU)
                        .nIn(100).nOut(15)
                        .encoderLayerSizes(120, 60, 30)
                        .decoderLayerSizes(30, 60, 120)
                        .pzxActivationFunction(Activation.IDENTITY)
                        .reconstructionDistribution(new BernoulliReconstructionDistribution(Activation.SIGMOID.getActivationFunction()))
                        .build())
                .pretrain(true).backprop(false)
                .build();
```

However, `VariationalAutoencoder` seems to be designed for training (and providing) mappings from an input to an encoded version, i.e. a vector of size 100 to a vector of size 15 in above example configuration.

However, I'm not particularly interested in the encoded version, but would like to train a mapping of a 100-vector to itself. Then, I'd like to run a other 100-vectors through it and get back their reconstructed versions.

But even when looking at the API of of the `VariationalAutoencoder` (or `AutoEncoder` too), I can't figure out how to do this. Or are those layers not designed for this kind of "end-to-end usage" and I would have to manually construct an autoencoding network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how to use the VAE layer to extract averaged reconstructions [from the variational example](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/unsupervised/variational/VariationalAutoEncoderExample.java#L163).

There's two methods for getting the reconstruction from a variational layer.  The standard is `generateAtMeanGivenZ` Which will draw samples from the layer and give you the average.  If you want raw samples you can use `generateRandomGivenZ`.  See [the javadoc page](https://deeplearning4j.org/doc/org/deeplearning4j/nn/layers/variational/VariationalAutoencoder.html) for all the other methods.